# How to get js function into webWorker via importScripts

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a worker.js file:

```
self.importScripts('/static/utils/utils.js')

onmessage = (e) => {
    let a = e.data[0]
    let b = e.data[1]
    let c = func1(a,b)
    postMessage(c)
}
```

The utils.js file looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
func1: function(a,b){
    return a+b
}
```

I keep getting error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at utils.js:1
```

Obviously require, and import and any other server side imports aren't working but I'm not sure why it's having a problem with my importScripts -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts

Comment: Where did you get `module.export` from? The answer to your problem is right there in the error message.

Comment: That doesn't support CommonJS modules.  Use browserify or Webpack.

Comment: I mistyped.. exports. I am able to reference them np from my test framework just unable to get them into the workerjs. @SLaks how to recommend starting to get this working with webpack. I've tried a few libraries with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to **pack your worker with webpack**. If you don't want to do that, read below.

I usually write myself a polyfill for node require:

```
// This will not work in normal UI thread
// None of this should make it into production
function require(moduleName) {
    self.module = { exports: null };
    // Nasty sttuff right here, probably should throw error instead
    if (moduleName == "fs")
        return null;
    // This part is especially unprofessional
    if (!moduleName.endsWith(".js"))
        moduleName += ".js";

    importScripts(moduleName);
    return self.module.exports;
}
```

This makes use of the fact that `importScripts` is synchronous. Note that this will still cause errors if you try to load native node modules (eg. `fs`) or if other `module` properties are used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `utils.js`:

```
(function () {
    self.func1 = function (a, b) {
        return a + b
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
//inside worker.js
self.addEventListener("message",(event)=>{
    importScripts("module.js")
    utils.print1()
    utils.print2()
})


//inside module.js
//setting a variable in global scope, allows worker.js to use it.
var utils = {
    print1(){
        console.log("This is a content from a module.")
    },
    print2(){
        console.log("This is a another content from a module.")
    }
}
```